# How can I specify a custom MANIFEST.MF file while using the Maven Shade plugin?

Tags: maven, javabeans, maven-shade-plugin, manifest.mf

When a project uses the Maven-jar-plugin, it's easy to include a custom manifest file in the jar, but I can't find a way to do the same thing with Maven shade. How can I use my own manifest file while using the "Maven-shade-plugin"?

**Additional details:**

My custom manifest file is located in "src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".
Maven is not including my file, instead it is being replaced in the final jar with a default Maven manifest file.

The reason I need a custom manifest file is to specify some JavaBeans classes in my manifest, for a swing component library. Multiple JavaBeans classes should be specified in the manifest file in the following format, as [described here](http://www.ewebprogrammer.com/java-beans/module3/javabeans-manifest-file.jsp). Note that the empty lines (and the line grouping) are important for marking JavaBeans classes in the manifest.

```
Name: SomeBean1.class
Java-Bean: True

Name: SomeBean2.class
Java-Bean: True

Name: SomeBean3.class
Java-Bean: True
```

**A list of attempted solutions (these did not work):**

1. This code only works when using the Maven jar plugin (not shade).

   ```
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
         <archive>
           <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
         </archive>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
   ```
2. [This link](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifestFile.html) says "As with all the examples here, this configuration can be used in all plugins that use Maven Archiver, not just Maven-jar-plugin as in this example." Based on that advice, I tried the following code, but this did not work either. (Maven still replaced my manifest file with the default manifest file.)

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.4.3</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>shade</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration> 
                       <archive>
                           <manifestFile>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                       </archive>
                       <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                       <shadedClassifierName>core</shadedClassifierName>
                       <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                       <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>      
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```
3. I cannot use the shade "ManifestResourceTransformer" as [described here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ManifestResourceTransformer) to do the job, for the following reason. I need to add JavaBeans classes to my manifest file as described above under "additional details". However, if I add manifest entries using the shade ManifestResourceTransformer, those entries are inserted into the manifest file in an unpredictable (random-seeming) ordering. For specifying JavaBeans classes, the ordering of the manifest entries (the line order) is important.
4. I attempted to use IncludeResourceTransformer, but the below code produces the following error: "Error creating shaded jar: duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF".

   ```
                   <configuration> <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                       <shadedClassifierName>core</shadedClassifierName><createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                       <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>    
                       <transformers>
                           <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                               <resource>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</resource>
                               <file>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</file>
                           </transformer>
                       </transformers>  
                   </configuration>
   ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following pom configuration allows the programmer to replace the manifest file created by Apache Maven Shade plugin, with a custom manifest file. The custom manifest file should be placed in this directory in the maven project: "src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        ...
                        <transformers>

                            <!-- Don't do this: Avoid adding anything that makes shade create or modify a manifest file.
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            -->

                            <!-- Add a transformer to exclude any other manifest files (possibly from dependencies). -->
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.DontIncludeResourceTransformer">
                                <resource>MANIFEST.MF</resource>
                            </transformer>

                            <!-- Add a transformer to include your custom manifest file. -->
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</resource>
                                <file>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</file>
                            </transformer>

                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```